# The new TSA airport scanners and tznius

Tags: halacha, current-events, travel, tznius-modesty

Is it OK as per Halacha to go through the new TSA scanners where they see you as if you are naked?

Comment: They don't actually see you naked. The machine detects metal and it shows up on a standard picture. Last I checked, machines don't have hirhurim (not yet, anyway).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Rav Moshe Shternbuch](http://www.vosizneias.com/46464/2010/01/07/jerusalem-vin-exclusice-rav-shternbuch-airport-full-body-scans-kosher) reportedly sees no problem with it.

Comment: Just to add my own experience: Rabbi Hershel Welcher, president of the Vaad HaRabbonim of Queens, was asked this question in front of his shul and said he didn't see the problem.

Comment: Did everyone else get the puns here?